# Wireless adaptor problem after upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, upgrade, 13.04

My wireless adapter was working probably after I used these two commands:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

But when I upgrade to 13.04, the command:

```
sudo modprobe -r b43 && sudo modprobe b43
```

...is not working. I ran `lshw -C network`:

```
lshw -C network
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network               
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0b:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=wl latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:efdfc000-efdfffff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX
       vendor: Broadcom Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 02
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=64
       resources: memory:ef9fe000-ef9fffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program
as super-user.
```

Please, I need some help.

Answer (score 0):

The `wl` driver is currently loaded for the adapter, you need to remove that first:

`sudo apt-get purge broadcom* bcmwl*`

The firmware for this card is installed the following way:

`sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer`

After a restart the `b43` driver should get loaded for the adapter, you can check it with `lshw -C network`.